# How to decrement a counter if a button is clicked the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code, each time a button is clicked it adds it to a counter as shown bellow, what I am trying to achieve is that if the same button is clicked the second time it must decrement the counter, currently if I press a single button multiple times it adds to a counter, I only want it to add to a counter when its clicked on the first time, the second time its clicked it must decrement the counter, I am trying to click each button only once and if  its clicked on the second time it must decrement the counter

```js
var counter = 0;

function count() {
  $('#notify').addClass("notification");
  $("#notify").html(counter);
}



$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  counter++;
  count();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketoptionslist">
  <a><button class="btn" >
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button ></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
</div>

<span id="notify" class="notification"></span>
```

and suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to build a toggle system? Ie. the third click should add one, and the fourth click should subtract

Comment: It sounds like the counter will always toggle between `0` and `1` when you click.  Have you thought about how you could achieve that within your `.on('click',...` handler?

Comment: use simply a flag and declare it as false and in in button click check if its fals e or true if false then it will be first click and then do your logic and change it as true and in the coming hits you can check the same logic if it is true then go for decrement logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add some class to button to store the state about whether it should increase the counter or decrease it.

I am adding class `increment` to do this. See the code below...

```js
var counter = 0;

function count() {
  $('#notify').addClass("notification");
  $("#notify").html(counter);
}



$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("increment");
  
  if($(this).hasClass("increment"))
    counter++;
  else
    counter--;
    
  count();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketoptionslist">
  <a><button class="btn" >
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button ></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
</div>

<span id="notify" class="notification"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve this is to toggle a class on the clicked buttons, then display the count of the number of buttons which have the given class. Also note that your HTML is invalid, as you cannot have a `button` element within an `a` element. Here's a working example:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $("#notify").html($('.btn.active').length);
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
.active { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketoptionslist">
  <button class="btn">click me</button>
  <button class="btn">click me</button>
  <button class="btn">click me</button>
  <button class="btn">click me</button>
</div>

<span id="notify" class="notification"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont like the idea of using a class to do that. Class should be used only to apply style to an element. For this purpose, I'd use data, has showed below.

```js
var counter = 0;

function count() {
  $('#notify').addClass("notification");
  $("#notify").html(counter);
}



$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  $(this).data('increment',!$(this).data('increment'));
  
  if($(this).data('increment'))
    counter++;
  else
    counter--;
    
  count();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketoptionslist">
  <a><button class="btn" >
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button ></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
</div>

<span id="notify" class="notification"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used a custom key `_clickCount` that is bound to the specific element that is clicked.
With a simple modulu check `% 2` you can check if it's clicked for the first or second time.

```js
var counter = 0;

function count() {
  $('#notify').addClass("notification");
  $("#notify").html(counter);
}

$('body .btn').on('click', function(e) {
  if (this._clickCount) {
    this._clickCount++;
  } else {
    this._clickCount = 1;
  };
  
  if (this._clickCount % 2 == 0) {
    counter--;
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
  console.log(this._clickCount);
  count();
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketoptionslist">
  <a><button class="btn" >
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button ></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
</div>

<span id="notify" class="notification"></span>
```

> **Note:**
>
> You don't have to pass the button-class `.btn` as second parameter in
>   `on()` because they are not added dynamically. You can just add them in the selector `$('body .btn')`

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra class and check for the class like this.

```js
var counter = 0;

function count() {
  $('#notify').addClass("notification");
  $("#notify").html(counter);
}

$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('click')) {
    $(this).removeClass('click');
    counter--;
    count();
  } else {
    counter++;
    $(this).addClass('click');
    count();
  }
  //console.log(counter);
});
```

```css
.notification {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 9px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 8px;
  height: 9px;
  line-height: 4px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #000;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background-color: #b60000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marketoptionslist">
  <a><button  class="btn" >
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button ></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
  <a><button class="btn">
  click me
  </button></a>
</div>

<span id="notify" class="notification"></span>
```